# How can I grab the row of data from a ggplotly in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Code Below.

I'm trying to use the `plotly_click` event to figure out what data is being selected. However, I can't figure out how to do it. The data provided by plotly_click is very minimal and doesn't include the grouping or groups at all. I don't have any JS experience, but I know there must be a way! My goal is to be able to select a data point and be able to grab the row it corresponds to in a data.frame `d1`

```
d1=structure(list(Topic = c("compensation", "manager", "benefits",
                         "family", "communication", "worklifebalance", "perks", "compensation",
                         "benefits", "manager", "communication", "worklifebalance", "family",
                         "perks", "benefits", "compensation", "manager", "communication",
                         "family", "worklifebalance", "perks"),
                  variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                       .Label = c("Prct", "Count"), class = "factor"),
                  value = c(2.23121245555964, 0.723305136692411, 0.576192227534633,
                         0.202280250091946, 0.190020840995464, 0.153242613706019,
                         0.0122594090964816, 0.913705583756345, 0.609137055837563,
                         0.50761421319797, 0.50761421319797, 0.304568527918782, 0.203045685279188,
                         0, 1.49977276170277, 1.21193758521436, 0.893803969095592,
                         0.439327374640206, 0.348432055749129, 0.242387517042872,
                         0.0757460990758976),
                  group = c("APAC", "APAC", "APAC", "APAC",  "APAC", "APAC", "APAC",
                            "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA",
                            "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS",
                            "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS")),
             .Names = c("Topic", "variable", "value", "group"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
             row.names = c(NA, -21L))


library(needs)
needs(
  stringr,
  data.table,
  tm,
  ggplot2,
  wordcloud,
  readxl,
  dplyr,
  quanteda,
  topicmodels,
  reshape,
  plotly,
  shiny,
  rCharts,
  ggthemes,
  shinyjs,
  shinyWidgets,DT,shinythemes,
  ggrepel,tidyverse,treemapify
)
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(plotlyOutput('keywords')),
  fluidRow(  verbatimTextOutput("selection")) )



server = function(input,output){
  output$keywords = renderPlotly({


    d0 = d1
    p = ggplot(d0, aes(reorder(Topic,-value), value)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = value),
        shape = 16,
        size = 3,
        show.legend = F) +
      facet_wrap(~ group)+
      theme_minimal()
    ggplotly(p)


  })
  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click")
      cat("You selected: \n\n")
      as.list(s)

  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could try:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(plotlyOutput('keywords')),
   fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("selection")),
   fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))
)   

server = function(input,output){
output$keywords = renderPlotly({

d0 = d1
key <- row.names(d0)
d0 <- data.frame(d3, key)  

p = ggplot(d0, aes(reorder(Topic,-value), value, key = key)) +
        geom_point(aes(colour = value),
                   shape = 16,
                   size = 3,
                   show.legend = F) +
        facet_wrap(~ group)+
        theme_minimal()
      ggplotly(p)


    })
    output$selection <- renderPrint({
      s <- event_data("plotly_click")
      cat("You selected: \n\n")
      data.frame(s)
    })

    selection2 <- reactive({
      s <- event_data("plotly_click")
      cat("You selected: \n\n")
      df <- data.frame(s)
    })

    output$table1 = renderDT({
      d2 <- d1 %>% filter(key == selection2()$key)
      d2 
  }) 
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @TedMosby. If you define `key` outside the `server` function it will work. It does it make sense. Click on one point and the table will appear. I have made the changes in my post above.

Comment: Almost works. If you look at the groupings, those are off. If I click on a point in AMERICAS, the group of APAC shows up.

Comment: @TedMosby, adding this: `d0 <- cbind(d0, key)` on top of the code seems to fix the issue.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it need to be outside of the server function? The data is reactive so placing it out of the scope of everything doesn't work.

Comment: I can't test the code now but it should work now inside

Answer (score 2):

I have only used `plotly_selected` but I assume `plotly_clicked` should be similar. `plotly_selected` will be triggered when you brush over the plot.

Here is an example:

```
# 'data' is the data frame you used to draw the plot
brushed_data <- reactive({
  d <- event_data("plotly_selected")

  data_key <- d$key

  if (!is.null(data_key) && length(data_key) > 0) {
   # if it's not the row names, can be any column 'data[data$key %in% data_key,]
   data[rownames(data) %in% data_key,]
  } else {
    data.frame()
  }
})
```

The key is specified when you draw your plot, in my case, I pass `key = rownames(data)` to `add_markers`

**EDIT** Adapted the Plotly website example using ggplot2 and `plotly_click`

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brush")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
      geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ cyl)
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
  })

  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    req(d)
    print(mtcars[d$key, ])
  })

  output$brush <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    req(d)
    print(mtcars[d$key, ])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to facet by, say, cyl in your data? That doesn't work anymore

Comment: @TedMosby  adding `+ facet_wrap(~ cyl)` after geom_point() still works